# insertが遅い原因

Tags: centos, mariadb

Webアプリケーション経由でDBにデータをinsertしているのですが、
ある日からinsertが遅くなりました。同じくらいの量のデータでも以前は、
30秒から1分ほどで終わっていた処理が今は10分以上かかります。
（一応処理は、時間がかかりますが成功します。）

一方、同じDBをdumpしてローカルの仮想環境に簡易構築した同じWebアプリケーションでは、
実働のものよりメモリ等もスペックは低いですが、1分ほどでinsertの処理が終了します。

このような場合、どういったことが原因として考えられるのでしょうか。
my.cnfの設定？ HDDなどのI/Oの問題？ ネットワークの問題？
調査する方法・解決策等を教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

質問にあるように、DBをダンプして別環境に再構築して速度向上が見られるのであれば、
DBの断片化が発生していると考えられます。

この場合、「`OPTIMIZE TABLE テーブル名`」を実行すると、事象が改善すると思います。

＃mariadbは専門ではないので、机上調査の上での回答です。

---

以下、補足です。

一般的に、SQL文の実行が遅い時の調査方法は「`EXPLAIN`」による実行計画の確認があります。
SQL文の部分(例えば、`WHERE`句の条件式の1つ)ごとに処理時間が見えると思うので、それを
確認する方法があります。
(この場合、SQL文を見直すことになります)

また、`INSERT`が遅くなる場合、インデックスの更新に時間がかかっていることもあります。
多数のインデックスを張っている、多量のレコードを格納している、等を確認する方法があります。
(この場合、テーブル設計を見直すことになります)

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。調べてみたのですが、テーブル数が多いためmysqlchek -o コマンドで該当DBを一括最適化を行おうと考えております。実行する前に現環境を物理バックアップ(/usr/lib/mysql)をとって、テスト環境でリストア(cpコマンドなどで)を行なって、テスト環境で断片化の改善が見られるかを確認してから本番環境で最適化を実行しようと考えています。物理バックアップをリストアした場合も断片化した状態を再現できますでしょうか？ 環境を丸ごとバックアップしてリストアしないと再現できないでしょうか？　重ねての質問を申し訳ございません。

Comment: MySQLのマニュアル「[バックアップとリカバリの種類](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/backup-types.html)」(日本語ページなので5.6)にDBファイルの物理コピーの方法が記載されているので、コメントの方法で大丈夫と思います。(なお、バックアップの際にMySQLの停止が必要と思います)